# Android Webview does not open CSS/JAVASCRIPT server side php

Tags: java, android, xamarin, webview, loading

i am using xamarin android but if you provide java code is also good.
I noticed when i open certain url pages, i get a blank page but if i open thesame webpage in google chrome on my test device it opens nicey.

I have done the following with no luck:

```
WebView web_view = view.FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView1);
            web_view.SetWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
            web_view.Settings.LoadWithOverviewMode = true;
            web_view.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            web_view.Settings.CacheMode = CacheModes.Normal;
            web_view.Settings.UserAgentString = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36";
            web_view.Settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
            web_view.Settings.DatabaseEnabled = true;
            web_view.Settings.UseWideViewPort = true;
            web_view.Settings.SetPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.On);
            web_view.LoadUrl("url_here");
```

I have also added "android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"" in my android application tag manifest.

Offcourse i also added the internet permission and i using https but i get a blank page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue...
First create a webviewclient class :

```
public class MyBabyclient : WebViewClient
    {
        public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, IWebResourceRequest request)
        {
            view.LoadUrl(request.Url.ToString());
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Then assign it to your webview :  web_view.SetWebViewClient(new MyBabyclient());

More info can be seen here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/controls/web-view